# no pre-installed ubuntu one application or software

Tags: ubuntu-one

I installed ubuntu 16.04 LTS, but there is no ubuntu one software, not in ubuntu software center also..Though it is showing selected in unity tweak tool.How can I get it. Please reply.

Comment: Related: //en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_One

Answer (score 2):

Ubuntu One used to provide a cloud storage service. You probably found an artifact of that service. It was discontinued in 2014.

For details see http://blog.canonical.com/2014/04/02/shutting-down-ubuntu-one-file-services/